# Kendo TreeView display undefined

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I had this sample kendo treeview demo, it work fine if I use same name but when I use different name `ledger/group` it read as `undefined`. Any idea how to fix this?

[Full demo here](https://dojo.telerik.com/oqefAjEP)

```js
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataBound: function(){
   this.expand('.k-item');
  },
  template: "<span #if(item.active=='n'){# style='color:red' #} #>#:item.group#</span>" ,
  dataSource: [
    { ledger: "Title 1st", active:"y", items: [
      { group: "subTitle1", active:"y" },
      { group: "subTitle2", active:"n" },
      { group: "subTitle3", active:"y" },
      ]},{
    ledger: "Title 2nd", active:"n"}
  ]
});
```

Comment: Can you also share a code snippet showing where you are trying to use `ledger/group` please?

Comment: not sure i understand what you want. Basically it only fetch data from the database and display into kendo treeview. In addition, I wanted to make text color 'red' if active = 'n'.. ledger/group only to differentiate the name.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a conditional statement within your template. Something like this should do it:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataBound: function(){
    this.expand('.k-item');
  },
  template: "<span #if(item.active=='n'){# style='color:red' #} #>#: item.group != null ? item.group : item.ledger #</span>" ,
  dataSource: [
    { ledger: "Title 1st", active:"y", items: [
      { group: "subTitle1", active:"y" },
      { group: "subTitle2", active:"n" },
      { group: "subTitle3", active:"y" },
    ]},{
      ledger: "Title 2nd", active:"n"}
  ]
});
```

[Full demo here](https://dojo.telerik.com/oqefAjEP/4)